# Split Algorithm on C++

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, genetic-algorithm, stl-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have an array with 8 elements:

```
a[8] = {9, 7, 6, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4}
```

I want to divide 8 elements to 3 group. Each group is the sum of 1 or more element. The sum of each group is most similar.

Comment: Please describe what you already tried, and the specific problem you encountered.

Comment: Since you tagged this with both genetic-algorithm and evolutionary-algorithm, I'm assuming you were thinking of using some sort of evolutionary computation. Is that correct? At face value, this problem doesn't seem like a great candidate for evolutionary computation, because it is hard to come up with a fitness function that would increase gradually. You could use negative summed difference between the three sums as your fitness function, and have your mutation operator swap elements between partitions, but each swap will change sums drastically. This might get better with larger arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing the [k-partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_k-partition_problem) with k=3.

Unfortunately, this problem is known to be (strong) [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), so there is no known efficient solution to it (and the general belied is one does not exist).

Your best hope will be brute force search: create all partitions to 3 groups, and choose the best one out of them. If you are dealing with 8 elements - that should be possible, but it will quickly become too slow for larger arrays I am afraid.